# Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2012 cannot delete file even as Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, deleting

I cannot get [Blender3D](https://www.blender.org/) to run on my AWS EC2 instance. I get a message telling me that my system does not use 3D hardware acceleration.

I have all my drivers installed (NVidaGRID, etc) and have disabled the "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" in `Device Manager`.

No joy. Then, I came across the following post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=500885&

A user mentions that we should delete the `BasicDisplay` file `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\BasicDisplay.sys`.

However, I cannot delete this file because I do not have permissions.
I am logged into my EC2 instance via `RDP` (remote desktop protocol) as Administrator. I've taken ownership of the directory `system32` and even tried with ownership of the `Windows` directory.

No joy.

Then I checked if there was a file in the directory that was locked and forced all files to be closed.

No joy.

Next, I tried running the command prompt as Administrator to remove the file.

No Joy.

Tried changing the attributes: Access denied.

Finally, I tried creating a new user account, gave it `RDP` permissions, made it an administrator, gave it ownership of `system32` directory and wait for it...

No joy.

Seriously. What the *$@% is the problem here? I cannot log in via safe mode. How can I delete this file?

Comment: the file might be actively being used by some process. just install process explorer, press Ctrl+F and type filename to see if it is opened by any process

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution. AWS is definitely not easy especially when it comes to going into safe mode and then being able to RDP. Open an elevated command prompt, type `MSCONFIG`, go to BOOT/select safe boot/select network/select boot log/select base video/select OS boot info. Restart. You will be able to then delete `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\BasicDisplay.sys` once you have taken ownership from Trusted Installer. I have tried it several times and it works.

Comment: fwiw, I was pretty hopeful about this advice, but I could never make it work. I'm curious if it has worked for anyone else.